# Order Firebase data in table view cell by child value

Tags: ios, sorting, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Why doesn't think code sort data by the value of the child "scoreTotal"?  I've tried sorting by the value scoreTotal and query by child "scoreTotal" but it's still showing up in the table view in alphabetical order of the cell title.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellMale", for: indexPath as IndexPath)

    let comp = comps[indexPath.row]

    let dbRef1 = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Live Scoring Male/\(String(describing: comp.name!))/scoreTotal")

    dbRef1.queryOrdered(byChild: "scoreTotal").observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let scoreTotal = snapshot.value as! Double

        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String(scoreTotal)
        self.comps.sorted(by: {$0.scoreTotal > $1.scoreTotal})

    })

    cell.textLabel?.text = comp.name

    return cell

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are querying for data inside the cell rendering function where you need to use that data. Firebase calls are asynchronous. You must call for the data you need BEFORE you need it, then respond to it arriving as it comes in.

When `cellForRowAt` is called, don't forget that `UITableView` recycles cells. You're not supposed to (not allowed to) take strong references to them inside that function, and you certainly should not change the table's source data (`comps[]` in your case) from within that function!

Every application is different, but typically the "right" pattern here would be to query for this data in a `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` override in your class. Call `reloadData` on the tableview (or appropriate batch update functions) as new data arrives that you want to be drawn. Inside your `cellForRowAt` override, you will then have this data available immediately, and will be able to render it properly.

You should definitely take a look at FirebaseUI (https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS). It includes data sources for both Table and Collection Views that handle all of this logic for you, and will make your life a lot easier.